# JavaScript execution flow on Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, execute

I have one question about javascript and WebView in android. I have not found answer on it.

When I trying to load web page using loadData (javascript enabled in web view settings) I can't understand working flow of javascript execution (seems like no execution of some javascript code ). Code of page is below(example):

```
<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no initial-scale=1.0' />
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var init = function() {
var uuu = window.uuu = {};
}

window.zzz = window.uuu;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">/
(function() {
  var c = window.c = {};
})();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">   ......  some javascript ..... </script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; background-color:transparent;">
<div align="center">
<script>   ..... some javascript ..... </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page after loading not execute any javascript and start working only if all javascripts injects by loadUrl("javascript:" + ....); This is not good solution ( body can be complex and can contain javascript or not contain it ). How get working javascript similar on desktop browsers ?

Comment: It have to be working.. test your code inside of Desktop Browser... it seems that there is JavaScript error somewhere..

Comment: Looks like You are right. If i try very simple example - all works correct.

Comment: I found my problem - // style comments in javascript stops correct web view loading if this comment inside function body. Same javascript works fine on desktop and iPhone webview.

Comment: @dmtrlbdv why is that?